# Почему установщик не видит новых версий библиотеки?

Tags: python, pip

Я в python новичок. Я хочу установить библиотеку [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) версии 2.3.0, и она точно существует.

Если выполнить команду `pip install geopy` то у меня устанавливается версия **1.23.0**

Я пытался сделать так: `pip install geopy==2.3.0` , тогда в командной строке мне выдает такую ошибку:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geopy==2.3.0 (from versions: 0.93, 0.94, 0.94.1, 0.94.2, 0.95, 0.95.1, 0.96.0, 0.96.1, 0.96.2, 0.96.3, 0.97, 0.97.1, 0.98, 0.98.1, 0.98.2, 0.98.3, 0.99, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.13.0, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.19.0, 1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.23.0) No matching distribution found for geopy==2.3.0

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А какая у вас версия питона?

Comment: @andreymal разные стоят, в том числе и 3.10 есть, она самая большая у меня

Comment: Моё чутьё мне настойчиво говорит, что вы пытаетесь устанавливать на питоне 2.7

Comment: @andreymal а как выполнить установку на другой версии питона?

Comment: В общем случае просто найдите где у вас стоит свежий питон, в каком каталоге, и там где-то у него и `pip` должен быть в каком-то подкаталоге. И вот именно оттуда `pip` и запускайте.

Comment: Какая у вас операционная система? Если Windows, пробуйте устанавливать через `py -3.10 -m pip install ...`. Если Python 2.7 установлен, лучше его удалить, если он вам не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Для Python3 вот так попробуйте установить

```
pip3 install geopy
```